# Inheritance of abstract classes with configuration in constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, abstract

I come from the PHP world and am currently implementing my first TypeScript project. Unfortunately many things don't work here that I'm used to in PHP for a long time. One of these things is the following code example:

```
abstract class Car {

    constructor() {
        this.initCar()
    }

    abstract initCar(): void

    abstract start(): void
}

class SportCar extends Car {

    private engine = ''
    
    initCar(): void {
        this.engine = 'V8'
    }

    start() {
        console.log(`I'm starting the ${this.engine} engine.`)
    }
}

const sportCar = new SportCar()
sportCar.start()
```

My expectation is that *I'm starting the **V8** engine.* will be output. but unfortunately *I'm starting the  engine.* will be output.

1. what does TypeScript + JavaScript do with this example?
2. how do I solve such cases where I want to use the constructor of an abstract class to configure the child objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be answered by looking at the Javascript output:

```js
"use strict";
class Car {
    constructor() {
        this.initCar();
    }
}
class SportCar extends Car {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.engine = '';
    }
    initCar() {
        console.log('initCar');
        this.engine = 'V8';
    }
    start() {
        console.log(`I'm starting the ${this.engine} engine.`);
    }
}
const sportCar = new SportCar();
sportCar.start();
```

As you can see, the `this.engine = ''` line is executed after the constructor.

I think this is pretty surprising behavior too. The easiest way to solve it for this case is to not initialize `engine` as an empty string, because after all... why would you? You're always going to overwrite it.

```js
class SportCar extends Car {

    private engine!: string;
    
    initCar(): void {
        console.log('initCar');
        this.engine = 'V8';
    }

    start() {
        console.log(`I'm starting the ${this.engine} engine.`)
    }
}
```